# SQLite.Interop.dll only copied with Debug build

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

A developer recently added the SQLite.Core NuGet package to one of our solutions to work as an in-memory database for testing purposes.  Everything works great when building the solution using the Debug configuration; however, the tests fail when using the Develop or Release configurations.

What I found is the x64 and x86 SQLite.Interop DLLs are being copied to the output folder ONLY when building with the Debug configuration.  I could find nothing different in the .csproj file between the configurations that would explain this behavior.

To get around the problem, I added the following property group to the .csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup> 
    <ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CopySQLiteInteropFiles>false</CopySQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And added DeploymentItemAttributes to the test class so the DLLs are copied to the test folder.

I don't believe this should be required every time we want to use SQLite.

**What is the correct way to add SQLite to a project so it simply works without all of these additional steps?**

We are running Visual Studio 2015 and the solution is targeting .NET 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

We've added a `System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets.user` file containing the property group you described beneath the `System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets` file installed in the NuGet package directory.

This way, you don't need this in every project.

I'm not super-enthusiastic about this approach, though, since now we need to check in a file in a NuGet install folder in the versioning system, and reconsider it when upgrading `System.Data.SQLite.Core`.